# real analysis continuous definition question

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here is the definition

> **Let $E$ be a subset of $R$ and let $f$ be a real-valued function on $E.$ Then $f$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $E$ for every open subset $V$ of $R$.**

1. I think this definition means that if the function $f$ is open in continuous on $E$, $f$ inverse should be open is it right?
2. The proof said (from the book)

proof.

> suppose $f$ discontinuous on $E$ and $V$ is a open subset of $R.$ If $f^{-1}(V) =    ∅$, we are done.

The book proof said that if we show for open $V \subset R$ that $f^{-1}(V) =    ∅$ then the proof is done. I do not understand what this means

I do not understand this part, can you explain this sentence?

---

Here is the full proof from the book

> Proof.  Recall that a set U ⊂ E is open in E if for every p ⊆ U there
>   exist $\delta$ >0 such that  $N_{\delta}(p)  ∩ E$  ⊂ U. suppose $f$ discontinuous on $E$
>   and $V$ is a open subset of $R$ if $f^{-1}(V) =    ∅$, we are done.,
>   suppose p is in $f^{-1}(V)$. Since  V is open , there exists  ϵ >0 such
>   that  $N_ϵ(f(p)) ⊂ V$. Since f is continuous at p, there exists a $\delta$>0
>   such that $f(x) ⊆ N_ϵ(f(p))$ for all $ x ⊆ N_\delta(p)  ∩ E....$ something like
>   this

Comment: what is proof saying? point 2 is not clear. can you explain it clearly

Comment: Also a function is not open or closed, sets are.

Comment: @tst Not true. Open functions preserve open sets (mostly seen in Topology). So the statement here would be that $f$ is continuous $\iff$ $f^{-1}$ is open. Btw: What is $\Phi$ ?

Comment: @Kimchi : Instead of $\Phi$ I think you mean $\emptyset$ no?

Comment: sergio , yes i correct it

Comment: 1. is not true. [There are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) functions $f$ with the property that the image of *any* (non-empty) open interval, no matter how small, is the entire real line. Any such function is highly discontinuous.

Comment: (But maybe you meant something else, "$f$ is open in continuous on $E$" really does not mean anything.)

Comment: Did you want to write *suppose $f$ is continuous on $E$* instead of *suppose $f$ discontinuous on $E$*? BTW you could tell us at least the name of the book.